# how to addition new value with answer value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am trying to **add new value** in **eval value** but it replaces it. How can I add, subtract, divide and multiply with answer value?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var evaluated = false;
  $(".oprator").click(function() {
    const val = evaluated ? $(this).text() : ($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
    $(".input").val(val)
    evaluated = false;
  });

  $("#butnplus").click(function() {
    $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
  });
  $("#equal").click(function() {
    $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
    evaluated = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
<button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
<button id="butnplus">+</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Could you please provide more detail of user interaction and expected result?

Comment: I am trying to say how to make this [5+5=10] then I want to add new value like this.[5+5=10+5=15]

Comment: When first entering 5 + 5 = then adding + 5 to the displayed 10 it results in 15. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am wanting